# Java equivalent of Visual Basic Format$

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I am analyzing a VB system when I stumbled upon the following code snippet. This is my first time reading VB code and this may be a trivial question.

```
.
.
Format$(txt & "/02/20", "gee")
.
.
```

My question is, what does "gee" stand for? Is it a date format or something? I cannot find the string anywhere else in the code.  If it is a format type, what could it possibly be its equivalent in Java? I found out that Format$ in VB functions similarly to Java String.format().

Here is what the VB documentation says about Format$():

> Function Format$(Expression, [Format], [FirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek
>   = vbSunday], [FirstWeekOfYear As VbFirstWeekOfYear = vbFirstJan1]) As String
>       Member of VBA.Strings
>       Formats an expression

Comment: Have you tried running this separate to see what the output is, it looks to me the "gee" contains no valid format characters.

Comment: One menaing from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gee: Used as a mild expletive or exclamation, as of surprise, enthusiasm, or sympathy. :) Really, this function always returns "gee" and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using Visual Basic's Immediate window. It seems that "gee" is used for conversion from the Western Date to [Japanese Imperial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar) years.

Using immediate window:

```
? Format$( "2012/02/20", "gee")
Output -> H24
```

Another example:

```
? Format$("123123123", "#,##0")
Output -> 123,123,123
```

**NOTE:**

It seems that the above example using "gee" does not work with PC's having different regional settings. My VB6 is in English but my OS is a Japanese Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet will **always** evaluate to "gee". **EDIT** *This turns out not to be the case, see [nmenego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979295/15639)!*

It sounds like someone was experimenting with the `Format` function, and forgot to delete the experiment from the code!

If you'd like to learn more about `Format` have a look at the full VB6 documentation on [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262745%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and the [format specifiers for dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263414%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: I solved it using Visual Basic's Immediate window. It seems that "gee" is used for conversion from the Western Date to Japanese years. That is:

Comment: Interesting, maybe it depends on your regional settings or your version of VB6. In *my* Immediate window `? Format$( "2012/02/20", "gee")` outputs `gee`. English VB6, English UK regional settings.

Comment: Same here, Estonian settings - only "gee" is produced.

Comment: How do you retrieve the regional settings of VB6? So that I can write mine here for the reference of other people.

Comment: **Windows regional settings**: On Windows XP, Start-Control Panel-Regional and Language Options. I have "Regional Options" set to "English (United Kingdom)". **Visual Basic 6 version** I've [read](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236404) that Microsoft released localised versions of VB6, including a Japanese version. I know I have the English version because, well, I'm English & I'm afraid I only speak English & we bought the English version! I'm not sure how you could tell whether you have the Japanese version - I would *expect* the VB6 IDE menus etc. to be in Japanese, but I'm not sure.

Comment: My PC's regional settings are in Japanese. That is, my Windows menus and all are in Japanese script, but my VB6 is in English. I'll revise my above answer to put this in to note. Thanks @MarkJ.